# Why is force and AsPlainText required for secure string

Tags: powershell

I'm currently learning PowerShell through online tutorials.

What is the benefit of/why do examples use `-Force` and `-AsPlainText` when creating a secure string?

```
$password = 'P@ssw0rd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit of using those arguments, rather they are required to show that you understand that your string is not secure, despite the fact you've now placed it in a `SecureString`.  Because you've passed it as plain text, it's already in memory in an insecure manner.

`-AsPlainText` shows that you want to pass in it as a plain text parameter.  [`-Force` is documented as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring#-force):

> Confirms that you understand the implications of using the *AsPlainText* parameter and still want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `-Force` suppresses the confirmation prompt from `-AsPlainText`

```
$PW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force
```